# Calculate width of images for width of div? JS/jQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, width

I have a blog for a photographer I've designed/partially developed, he's paid a lot so I'm making everything as easy as can be to edit.

His gallery is in landscape view, so you have to slide from left to right to view photos. The problem with this is, when a new photo is added, the width needs to increase in the HTML/CSS.

How can I make it so that when a new photo is added, jQ calculates the width of all photos on the page and then returns a width that is used for the containing div so that they all fit??

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a pretty simple setup with a container div where id="photos" and a collection of img tags in it class="proofs":

```
var photo_width = 0;
$("#photos img.proofs").each(function(){
    photo_width += $(this).width();
});
```

This selects all the images tagged as photos with the .proofs class and iterates over them, adding up the width as it goes.  you should be able to alter this to match your setup.

From what I gather, webkit browsers will only calculate this correctly if the images have a width value set, so be sure your HTML code includes width attributes on images.  It's a good practice anyhow.

Comment: Awesome, I just wasn't exactly sure of how to do the calculation in js/jq, I've just started learning. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  Remember to add in extra for any margins, borders, outlines, or any other space that show between photos.  Glad to help!